# Creating a thread in a SharedLibrary raises segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I am very new to the linux OS so I am trying to design a shared library witch will start a thread i have the followin code :

1. The function init_log doesn't raise a segmentation fault it doesn't display noting in the log though can some one tell me why ?
2. The function pthread_create raises a segmentation fault i use derror() to print that in the log!

---

```
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) setup();

void init_log()
{
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
    openlog("TRACKER",LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
}

    void loop()
    {
        while (0 == 0)
        {
            syslog(LOG_NOTICE,"OK BOSS");
            sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    void setup()
    {
        pthread_t thread_id;
        init_log();
        syslog(LOG_NOTICE,"LIB LOADED"); // this doesn't display
        pthread_create(&thread_id,0,&loop,(void*)(NULL));
    }
```

**COMPILER LINKER PARAMS**

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project gt_trackers ****

make all 
Building target: libgt_trackers.so
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -shared -o "libgt_trackers.so"  ./main.o   
Finished building target: libgt_trackers.so

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: Can you post your compiler command?

Comment: Try adding the `-Wall` option to have the compiler show you all it doesn't like translating your code ... ;-)

Comment: How do you compile your program that uses this library? Don't you required  __-pthread__ in compile and link?

Comment: @Rohan I thought about that myself but the compiler doesn't raise any error.That's wierd I will add it anyway

Comment: @Rohan: The OP does not show the compiler flags in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `void loop()` should be `void *loop (void *)`

and the call the pthread_create should be

```
pthread_create(&thread_id,0,loop,NULL);
```

The prototype for pthread_create is as below. You should match the prototype of your loop function with "start_routine" mentioned below.

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

The other point is that, just providing the name of a function is sufficient to pass it's address. No need to add an `&` before it.

Link to Pthread Tutorial: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

As pointed out by alk, no need to typecast "NULL" also. Thanks alk. : )

Comment: @alk, It happens to me all the time. : ) Thanks for your comment. I had overlooked that. Updated my answer now.

Comment: I get this error now : void * loop(void *) - parameter name omitted

Comment: You can make it as void *loop(void *arg). It's just saying you didn't name the parameter while defining the function.

Comment: I still get segfault at 7f95638349e8 ip 00007f9563abfb91 sp 00007fff45aacb18 error 4 in libc-2.15.so[7f9563a37000+1b3000]

Answer (score 0):

Towards your first question. `syslog` doesn't print the log message directly to console. It writes to the file `/var/log/message` by default (at least in my case :-). You can use `tail -f /var/log/messages` to see your log message.

The `LOG_CONS` flag in `openlog` only means that

> Write directly to system console if **there is an error** while sending to system logger.

More information about `syslog` can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog)

FYI, here is a blog post about [linux log files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-log-files-location-and-how-do-i-view-logs-files/)